# C++ Macro definition including dot?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have some C++ code that I can't change, only by changing header files. I have the code and can compile it.

The issue is that I have a function pointer defined something like this (function pointer is kind of irrelevant to what I want to do):

```
foo.bar();
```

I would like change that with a macro or something to:

```
#define foo.bar() FunCall()
```

The issue as I understand is that it is not possible to use dots in a macro, is there any other way?

## Edit:

A bit more info. The code I get is intended to run a single instance, however I'm wrapping the code to run multiple instances in a class. That gives some headaches I'm trying to over come.

What I'm trying is either to use a macro and some inline functions or a complete third way:

```
 void function()
{
    foo.bar();
}
```

I need some code that could make above equivalent to:

```
void class::function()
{
    EventFuncTypedef f = foo.bar;
    (this->*f)();
}
```

Or

```
void class::function()
{
    class::FunCall();
}
```

The code above all work the issue is to try get option 1 or 2 executed by the original code.

Comment: Make a `struct` with function `bar()` implemented with `FunCall()`, and create a global variable `foo`. Then `foo.bar()` becomes the function call to `FunCall()`. Is it OK?

Comment: You cannot get rid of the dot. You only can use it in a more or less creative way.

Comment: A strict is not possible, that is actually what's already there. The code I get is created to run as a single instance and I'm trying to wrap the entire code into a class for multiple instances. That complicates it with member function pointers. I'm trying to think new creative ways to wrap it

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining a context where you can modify a header and recompile but not modify the source code. Are you aware how evil and dirty your attempted "solution" is? While this may seem crafty, there are 1000 ways this can go horribly wrong costing you days in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

with a macro and an helper:

```
struct FunCaller {
    static auto bar() {FunCall();}
};

#define foo FunCaller{}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't mention that I had it all wrapped in a class. But maybe this will still work? I can't foresee the consequences doing above but will try it out or something similar.